# Reverse complement DNA

Tags: python, bioinformatics, dna-sequence

I have this equation for reverse complementing DNA in python:

```
def complement(s): 
    basecomplement = {'A': 'T', 'C': 'G', 'G': 'C', 'T': 'A'} 
    letters = list(s) 
    letters = [basecomplement[base] for base in letters] 
    return ''.join(letters)
def revcom(s):
    complement(s[::-1])
print("ACGTAAA")
print(complement("ACGTAAA"[::-1]))
print(revcom("ACGTAAA"))
```

however the lines:

```
print(complement("ACGTAAA"[::-1]))
print(revcom("ACGTAAA"))
```

do not equal one another. only the top line gives an answer. the bottom just prints "NONE"

any help why this is?

Comment: I bet it prints `None`, not `"NONE"`.  That's actually an important distinction.  Remember, when asking for help with debugging, it is important to report the error *exactly* as it occurs.

Answer (score 7):

You forgot the `return` statement in `revcom`. Try this:

```
def revcom(s):
    return complement(s[::-1])
```

If you don't explicitly return a value from a function in Python, then the function returns `None`.

Answer (score 6):

Python3, including whole IUPAC alphabet for nucleotides:

```
def revcomp(seq):
    return seq.translate(str.maketrans('ACGTacgtRYMKrymkVBHDvbhd', 'TGCAtgcaYRKMyrkmBVDHbvdh'))[::-1]
```

In Python2:

```
from string import maketrans

def revcomp(seq):
    return seq.translate(maketrans('ACGTacgtRYMKrymkVBHDvbhd', 'TGCAtgcaYRKMyrkmBVDHbvdh'))[::-1]
```

Answer (score 4):

A pretty one liner to reverse complement a DNA sequence:

```
revcompl = lambda x: ''.join([{'A':'T','C':'G','G':'C','T':'A'}[B] for B in x][::-1])
print revcompl("AGTCAGCAT")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `return` the result from `revcom()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
`a = "AAAACCCGGT"
a= a[::-1]
print("reverse: "+a)
a = a.replace('A','a')
a = a.replace('T','A')
a = a.replace('a','T')
a = a.replace('C','c')
a = a.replace('G','C')
a = a.replace('c','G')
print("complement : "+a)`
```